# Why isn't this changing the height of the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to create a simple button.  For some reason, the width of the button will change, but the height won't.  Am I just doing something stupid?

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<span id='pauseButton'</span>";

var button = document.createElement("input");

button.type = "button";
button.value = "Pause";
button.style.height = "50px";
button.style.width = "50px";
button.onclick = function() {
    paused = !paused;
    button.value = paused && "Unpause" || "Pause";
}

document.getElementById("pauseButton").appendChild(button);
```

Comment: Looks like you're adding a button to the page, not changing the dimensions of one

Comment: I'm adding the button, then changing the dimensions.  The width changes correctly, but the height won't change.

Comment: Seems to work ok [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9a47s6f4/). Also, there's no `>` on the opening `span` tag string on the first line of your script (fixed in the fiddle). However, I noted the height was working even before fixing that.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to change the dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a div as your button than a button as your button. You'll have more control over it. See this example: [Resizing a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689427/resizing-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is nothing wrong with the code you have shown other than one missing '>' for span. In order to change the height of the button after it is created, assign the button an id, let's say 'button1' then change the height as:

```
document.getElementById("button1").style.height = "200px";
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/9a47s6f4/3/)**